# selecting data from two different times

Tags: sql

I am addressing to SQL Guru to solve my issue.
I have table having fields:
date, head, receipts and payments
I want to retrieve data from period 01-JUL-2014 to 31-AUG-2014 i.e upto balanc(receipts-payments) and from 01-sep-2014 to 30-sep-2014 i.e.current_month(receipt-payments)

(Note: above dates are parameter form here i define hard coded in order to clearly my issue)

Comment: So you want one column to be either `between 01-JUL-2014 and 31-AUG-2014 OR between 01-SEP-2014 and 30-SEP-2014`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What dbms are you using? MySQL? Or SQL Server? Or what else? Different dbms handle dates quite differently. What is your actual problem? You certainly know the WHERE clause and the OR operator; so what's missing?

Comment: I am using oracle 11g. I have to generate report that shows head, sum(receipts-payments) for two different times i.e current month and past 3 months etc

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from your_table
where (date >= '07/01/2014' and date <= '08/31/2014') or
      (date >= '09/01/2014' and date <= '09/30/2014')
```

Comment: Actually I need 3 columns i.e (head, upto_balance(sum(receipts-payments) between 01-jul-2014 to 31-aug-2014 and current_balance(current month) and these are group by functions